# error: no known class method for selector 'isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable'

Tags: ios, ionic2

I am using Diagnostic plugin to my IOS IONIC 2 app. i am getting an error when i do ionic build ios with production mode (--prod). Could anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance:)

> error: no known class method for selector
>   'isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable'
>       return [CMPedometer respondsToSelector:@selector(isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable)] &&
>   [CMPedometer isPedometerEventTrackingAvailable];

Comment: which version of XCode?

Comment: 7.3.1 version..

Answer (score 1):

Check [github issue](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/153). 
Also [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#version-32-for-ios-10).
Either update your Xcode version to 8.0 or above.

> cordova.plugins.diagnostic@3.2.0 adds support for the new
>   UserNotifications framework added in iOS 10. To build using v3.2.0,
>   you will need to use XCode 8+ because there's no way to conditionally
>   include a framework using the  tag in the plugin.xml.

Or downgrade your diagnostic plugin to 3.1